# Achievements button in game center

Tags: achievements

I published app with game center achievements to app store.  Achievements were working and updating.  I made a bug fix in non-game center code class and submitted the updated app version to store.  Now, I've noticed when I run the new version updated from the store, the game center no longer shows the app achievements button.  With the first version of the app, I had to do a lot of configurations thru iTunes Connect to define my leader board and achievements but with the update nothing changed so I left things alone.  Did I miss a step?  The updated version is showing the high scores correctly but the achievements are not showing.  In fact, when i enter game center directly and look for my app, the Achievements button in game center isn't even present for my app like it was in the first version and above the app title it displays, "No Achievements"

App target is iOS 6 for dev in objective-c with 4.3 backwards compatibility for iPhone.  I used the iPhone 6.0 simulator and a iPhone 4 for testing.

I've searched your FAQ and couldn't find anything about updated app submissions, so hope you can help.  If I missed something, a link will work but I really need to fix this problem since the app is "live".

Thanks for any help offered.

P.S.  The simulator shows my achievements button.  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer elsewhere.  I did miss a step.  Turns out Achievements must be re-selected and enabled for an app each time you upload a version even when you're not changing anything.  Thankfully, they have a "select all" option.  Looks like I'll be releasing another version just to re-enable my achievements.  sigh...